# Require user to enter password for X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection() selected CAC Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, x509certificate2

Within an `ASP.NET C#` application I want the user to have to **select a CAC certificate** and then **enter the password for the certificate**.

I am currently using the following code to allow a user to select a certificate:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.MY, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
var certificates = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Digital Certificates", "Select a certificate from the following list:", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
```

I then want the user to have to enter the password for the selected certificate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. And the code you posted is not the right way to do certificate selection.

The code runs on web server, and:

- the dialog will show certificates installed on web server, not on client
- user will never see this dialog, because it is invokes on a server and there is no one on server console to pick the certificate or close the dialog, once opened it will keep opened until you restart the web application.

this code will work while debugging the code/application locally, but once deployed it won't work the way you can imagine.